# Slash Command: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Webhook error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make an avatar command with slash commands and I keep on getting an error.

Here is my code and error. The name, description and options for the slash commands are in another file:

**Data Handler.js**

```js
async function createCmd(Client, guildId) {
    const data = [
        // ping
        {
            name: 'ping',
            description: "Return Websocket ping."
        },

        {
            name: 'slowmode',
            description: "Set Channel Slowmode.",
            options: [{
                name: "time",
                type: 'NUMBER',
                description: "Message Delay of the channel.",
                required: true
            }]
        },
        {
            name: 'avatar',
            description: 'Get a user\'s avatar.',
            options: [{
                name: 'target',
                type: 'USER',
                description: 'Choose a user',
                required: true,
            }]
        }


    ]


    await Client.guilds.cache.get(guildId)?.commands.set(data);
}
//834698665213952051



module.exports = { createCmd }
```

**Avatar.js**

```js
const Client = require("../../bot").Client
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports.run = async (inter) => {
    const user = inter.options.getUser('target')

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`${user.username}'s Avatar`)
        .setColor('#FFA500')
        .setImage(user.displayAvatarURL({
            dynamic: true,
            size: 1024
        }))
        .setTimestamp()
        .setDescription(`[Png](${user.avatarURL({ format: 'png' })}) | [Webp](${user.avatarURL({ dynamic: true })}) | [Jpg](${user.avatarURL({ format: 'jpg' })})`)
        .setFooter(`Requested by: ${inter.user.username}`, inter.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }));
    
    await inter.followUp({
        embeds: [embed]
    }); 
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: 'avatar',
}
```

**Error**

```js
C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\Vetlix-Utilities\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:349
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Unknown Webhook
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\Vetlix-Utilities\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:349:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\Vetlix-Utilities\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:50:14)
    at async InteractionWebhook.send (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\Vetlix-Utilities\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Webhook.js:192:15)
    at async Object.module.exports.run (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents\Vetlix-Utilities\SlashCommands\Utility\avatar.js:18:5) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/webhooks/834730290463244300/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246OTA4NzA2NjE5NzU4NjEyNDgwOnlONG1Md1NNazVCeVA5Slo1RldXTExlY3VmZVdMcGh6ZGI4NjJFYUZFWHNPWW8wbnVTaml0VTd5bldtbW9oVjQ5ekxCZ0NtV0NmM2FhQjVSTDY5bGhRSjFId1htRDRTUWJUMVN2SkZXVHZxNk5QQUFUZHU2MnRRNGE2dWM1NXZ3?wait=true',
  code: 10015,
  httpStatus: 404,
  requestData: {
    json: {
      content: undefined,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      embeds: [
        {
          title: "ShxZz's Avatar",
          type: 'rich',
          description: '[Png](https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/817779965856055317/128445caf9d891b9c1aedb609e3ee745.png) | [Webp](https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/817779965856055317/128445caf9d891b9c1aedb609e3ee745.webp) | [Jpg](https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/817779965856055317/128445caf9d891b9c1aedb609e3ee745.jpg)',
          url: null,
          timestamp: 2021-11-12T13:15:37.140Z,
          color: 16753920,
          fields: [],
          thumbnail: null,
          image: {
            url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/817779965856055317/128445caf9d891b9c1aedb609e3ee745.webp?size=1024',
            proxyURL: undefined,
            height: undefined,
            width: undefined
          },
          author: null,
          footer: {
            text: 'Requested by: Vetlix',
            icon_url: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/751405982562648146/32a3b7ada0724d08bec225ffa92aef84.webp'
          }
        }
      ],
      components: undefined,
      username: undefined,
      avatar_url: undefined,
      allowed_mentions: undefined,
      flags: undefined,
      message_reference: undefined,
      attachments: undefined,
      sticker_ids: undefined
    },
    files: []
  }
}
```

Node.js v17.0.0

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use [`CommandInteraction#followUp`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=followUp) an interaction you never replied to yet! Instead of using `CommandInteraction#followUp`, use [`CommandInteraction#reply`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=reply)

```js
await inter.reply({
    embeds: [embed]
})
```